# Get height of title view inside action sheet

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiactionsheet

I have made a custom nib for showing a persons photo, name and company info inside an app.
This nib is showing in the title area of an action sheet. At the moment i have managed to get the width of the area, but not the height - since i can't seem to find which view to check the size of.

In the `UIAlertController` i have taken its `contactAlertController.view.subviews[0]` to be able to get the width of the alert. But the height is the full height including buttons.

Is there any way to reach just the title view size? Because right now the main problem is that if a user has too long or too short name, it's not really wrapped ok, or it leaves too much space - since i have written the title as `"\n\n\n\n\n\n"`

#### My Code

```
let contactAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

        guard let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("userInfo", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? QuickInfoView else { return }
        customView.backgroundColor = .clear
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        customView.staffName.text = "\(user.givenName) \(user.surname)"
        customView.staffCompany.text = users[indexPath.row].companyName
        customView.staffTitle.text = users[indexPath.row].jobTitle
        customView.imageView.image = users[indexPath.row].userPhoto ?? UIImage(named: "nobody")!

        let viewToPlaceNibIn = contactAlertController.view.subviews[0]

        contactAlertController.view.addSubview(customView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewToPlaceNibIn, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                                     NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewToPlaceNibIn, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                                     NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewToPlaceNibIn, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
```

#### Image of the area size i need

[image: The view I need the size for is marked in red]

Comment: Don't try to "hack" `UIAlertController`, that's not recommended (cf. `The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`, and you are modifying it since you add a subview). In next iOS version, `contactAlertController.view.addSubview(customView)` could throw an error.

Comment: Apple Music uses this repeatedly, but I they seem to have built their own UIAlertController, like this one for example https://imgur.com/a/V4CnUuB

Comment: Music.app is made by Apple. They can do whatever they want, I don't think they go through validation except maybe for check if there is a bug/crash. They may even use they own UIAlertController which is a subclass of it, and do whatever they want, but for Apple to use a private API, that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefitting) method to get the calculated size of `UIView` after applying all its constraints.

Something like this:

```
let height = customView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
```

Of course you need to calculate it after setting all the data (labels' texts) for view. But @Larme was right in comments, it's not a good practice to customize `UIAlertController`. It would be better to write some `UserMenuViewController` with custom transition which will act like action sheet.